# Renyi fractal dimension $D_q$ for non-trivial $q$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, research-level, entropy, fractals

For a probability distribution $P$, Renyi fractal dimension is defined as

$$D_q = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{R_q(P_\epsilon)}{\log(1/\epsilon)},$$
where $R_q$ is Renyi entropy of order $q$ and $P_\epsilon$ is the coarse-grained probability distribution (i.e. put in boxes of linear size $\epsilon$).

The question is if there are any phenomena, for which using non-trivial $q$ (i.e. $q\neq0,1,2,\infty$) is beneficial or naturally preferred?

Answer (score 9):

The Rényi entropy of order $q = \frac{1}{2}$ apperas in several measures of pure states entanglement, please see for example: [Karol Zyczkowski, Ingemar Bengtsson:  Relatively Pure states entanglement](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0103027). This entropy has the property that for three state systems, 
the equientropy trajectories form circles with respect to the the Bhattacharyya distance, please see for example: [Bengtsson Zyczkowski: Geometry of quantum states](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=aA4vXMbuOTUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=GEOMETRY%20OF%20QUANTUM%20STATES&hl=en&ei=O1KRTtfuMoGSOoboncwN&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=GEOMETRY%20OF%20QUANTUM%20STATES&f=false), page 57.

Comment: Thank you for a nice example. However, $q=1/2$ is _semi-trivial_ (as it is conjugated to $q=\infty$).